# How do I raise the SmarterMail maximum scanning size for a message?

Tags: spam-prevention, spamassassin

I've got this one spammer sending really lengthy spam. They're brilliant, these guys are top notch and I'd suggest anyone who wants to spam the hell out well configured spamassassin protected boxes use them -- whoever they are. Here is an [example of this message](http://www.spamcop.net/sc?id=z5370441101z70cd8de014f52cc983104430d29e0334z).

Now when this message is processed I get this.

> 12:08:53 [50682] Message exceeds maximum scanning size, skipping content based checks.

That totally circumvents content based spam-checking. These messages they're sending are 688k, they don't come from a predictable source and they don't follow the same content -- though visually at least they follow the same template.

How do I raise SmarterMail's maximum message size to export to the SpamAssassin server?

Answer (score 1):

It's available for customization.

1. Log in as the Server Administrator.
2. Go to the `Security` tab (currently the shield icon)
3. Go to `Antispam Administration`
4. Click `Options`
5. Raise `Max message size to content scan`